# mergesort running faster than radix sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, radix-sort

I sorted a million random positive long numbers about 20 digits in length using my implementations of Merge sort and Radix sort.
The merge sort is significantly, almost 6 times, faster than the Radix sort.

I understand the time complexity of Radix sort also depends on the number of digits of the integers, but my merge implementation is beating my Radix implementation on all input sizes.

I am using my own queue class that has constant time push() and pop() in my radix sort. I am using arrays in the merge sort. Does this have something to do with this?

```
public static void RadixSort(long arr[]) {
            //Using 10 queues for each digit from 0-9.
    Queue q[] = new Queue[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        q[i] = new Queue();

    boolean allNumbersNotBucketed = true;
    long divisor = 1;

    while (allNumbersNotBucketed) {
        allNumbersNotBucketed = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            long digit = (arr[i] / divisor) % 10;


            q[(int) digit].enqueue(arr[i]);
                            //Put number into appropriate queue.

            if(digit > 0) allNumbersNotBucketed = true;
        }
        int pos = 0;
        divisor *= 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            while (!q[i].isEmpty())
                      arr[pos++] = q[i].dequeue();
            //Put queue contents back into array
    }
}
```

Here is the merge sort

```
public static void mergeSort(long[] a) {
    long[] tmp = new long[a.length];
    mergeSort(a, tmp, 0, a.length - 1);
}

private static void mergeSort(long[] a, long[] tmp, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int center = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, tmp, left, center);    //Divide 0 to middle
        mergeSort(a, tmp, center + 1, right); // Divide middle to center
        merge(a, tmp, left, center + 1, right); //Merge sorted lists
    }
}

private static void merge(long[] a, long[] tmp, int left, int right,
        int rightEnd) {
    long leftEnd = right - 1;
    int k = left;
    long num = rightEnd - left + 1;

    //Put smallest element into tmp while both lists
    //are non empty.
    while (left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd)
        if (a[left] < a[right])
            tmp[k++] = a[left++];
        else
            tmp[k++] = a[right++];

    while (left <= leftEnd)
        // Copy rest of first half
        tmp[k++] = a[left++];

    while (right <= rightEnd)
        // Copy rest of right half
        tmp[k++] = a[right++];

    // Copy tmp back
    for (long i = 0; i < num; i++, rightEnd--)
        a[rightEnd] = tmp[rightEnd];
}
```

**EDIT:**
I was rather stupidly using a LinkedList style Queue. I changed it to use a native array and now the merge sort is only twice as fast as compared to 6 times as fast earlier. The merge sort is still faster even for numbers only 10 digits long. I guess the BigO constants are in play here. Multiple million function calls to push() and pop() could also be to blame here.

Comment: can we see the implementation of your `merge` and `radix` sort

Comment: When you measure actual implementations then often the constants hidden by the BigOh become important. It's easy to do things that kill performance, and "my own queue class" is not a good sign.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with radix sort but after a quick Wikipedia search it seems like the time complexity for radix sort is `kn`, what if `k` happens to be bigger than `log n`?

Comment: Without seeing your implementations, there's no way to tell what the problem is.

Comment: The whole premise of radix sort is use direct addressing for everything.  Ie., arrays and memory offsets ONLY.  You should *never* use things like queues or linked lists for radix sorts!

Comment: You can checkout my implementation, no need for linked lists: https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/datastructure/ArrayUtils.java#L672

Comment: Also, for radix sort you normally don't extract each base 10 digit from the value but rather use the byte encoding directly as the radix (256 bins rather than 10).

Comment: Why don't you measure the time taken to sort n items using both sorts, where n is 1,000  10,000 100,000 1 million 10 million 100 million and then see how each grows as n increases. This is what big O measures. There are some algorithms for which the algorithm with the slowest O() growth doesn't start pulling ahead until the input size is extremely large.

Comment: Is the code written in Java?